# Book recommendation about MPC?

Tags: multiparty-computation

I have hard time finding introductory book talking about details of secure multiple party computation. Is there any recommendations? Thanks for the help.

Hope this is not off topic.

Comment: Sorry, reference requests are off-topic.

Comment: @fkraiem Since when? This (http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31217/structure-for-an-introductory-course-on-cryptography/) question, not only is not marked as off-topic, but was featured in the December's newsletter.

Comment: @Aventinus The question you link is obviously not a reference request.

Comment: Specifically, [literature recommendations are off topic](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1/do-we-want-literature-recommendations-and-similar-list-subjective-questions).

Comment: I kind of know this is off topic, but I have hard time finding resources talking about details (algorithmic details rather than brief examples) about secure multiparty computation protocols like Yao's garbled circuit. Thanks for the understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only book I know of regarding Secure Multiparty Computation is **Secure Multiparty Computation and Secret Sharing** by **Ronald Cramer**, **Ivan Bjerre Damgård** and **Jesper Buus Nielsen**. Yet, I could hardly classify it as introductory.

[This](http://www.cambridge.org/nl/academic/subjects/computer-science/cryptography-cryptology-and-coding/secure-multiparty-computation-and-secret-sharing?format=HBCambridge) is its official site.

Comment: Thank you Aventinus. That is also the only book I found useful. I guess I will try my luck on paper search.